# How to prevent user to enter specific times in datetimepicker?

Tags: datetimepicker

I am using [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker). I know how to restrict the user from entering specific dates.

```
$dates.filter(function(date){
            return (date.localDateValue() <= new Date().valueOf()-(24*60*60*1000));
        }).forEach(function(date){
            date.selectable = false;
        })
```

This code insode startDateBefore render, prevents user from entering dates 24h past the current date.

But now I want users to enter spectic times only. Like user can select only times between `10:05am  to 11:10pm`. I am unable to do that. Documentation doesn't specify on how to add filter to hour and minutes. Any help on that.

Answer (score 1):

In [Angular Date Time Picker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker), the `beforeRender` function also takes parameter called `view`. So we can use the `view==='hour'` to restrict users from entering past hours. I was missing the code for hours.

```
function startDateBeforeRender ($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {    
  var today = moment().valueOf();
  $dates.filter(function (date) {
    return date.localDateValue() < today -(24*60*60*1000)
  }).forEach(function (date) {
    date.selectable = false; 
  });


// to restrict hours by admin
if ($view === "hour") {
    // restict previous hours
    $dates.filter(function (date) {
    return date.localDateValue() < today
  }).forEach(function (date) {
    date.selectable = false; 
  })

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = new Date().valueOf();

if( date > 1000*(10*60+5) ){
    if( date < 1000*(23*60+10) ){
        //Code green, I repeat, CODE GREEN! 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the angular date time picker that I was using uses the concept of views(day, hours. minutes). The trick was on correct use of view.